# Why are my radiators not getting hot enough?

Tags: hvac, heating, radiator

I live in a newly build house with 9 radiators in it. I can have the heating on for 2+ hours and a few radiators get hot but not boiling hot while others are still Luke warm. I’ve tried bleeding them all, still the same issue.

What could cause this?

The boiler is a `Logic combi esp1 35`.

Comment: Make/model of boiler? Any settings on the boiler for temperature?

Comment: Boiler is Logic combi esp1 35. 
There is a setting for radiators and I’ve got that one eco friendly mode which is at 70

Comment: Have you _succeeded_ in bleeding them all? There may still be trapped air. Since it's a new build, this is something the HVAC contractor should have done - consider contacting him to ask him to stop by and fix his work. (Lean over his shoulder to learn while he's there.)

Comment: Also, consider turning off "eco mode" to see if it actually functions as desired.

Comment: There isn’t a function to eco mode off. When it’s on 70 it’s just eco mode automatically id have to put the temperature up

Comment: 70C = 158F. Which is plenty hot by regular hot water standards. But it is quite possible that by the time the water makes its way half-way through the radiator system that it has cooled off too much. So definitely try raising that, within whatever it considers "safe". (Mechanically speaking. Even 70C is not safe for a straight hot-water tap, but this is a closed system so that shouldn't be an issue.)

Comment: What would you recommend putting the temperature to?

Comment: Raise the water temp to whatever is necessary to properly heat your house. Raise it 10°C and see what happens. If that's not enough, bump it up again. Keep going until you're sufficiently warm. You won't get fined (except, perhaps by other members of the household) for not getting the setting exactly right the first time.

Comment: I’ll give that a go. So you don’t think it’s anything to do with the boiler?

Comment: What happens if you have it on for 4+ hours?

Comment: I’ve never had it on for 4+ hours with the prices it cost 

Comment: I’d also like to add. When the heating is on, you can hear clicking noises all the time

Comment: I’ve also just noticed in the living the radiator doesn’t have a thermostat value? Surely that’s not right?